# Converting a MATLAB GUI to .exe with trial version of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

I am using MATLAB 2015a trial version. I developed a MATLAB GUI, and I want to convert it to a .exe file, which I will be able to open when my trial will be over.

I searched the web and found out that I have to use MATLAB Compiler in order to convert it. I installed MATLAB Compiler successfully using MCR_R2014a_win64_installer.exe‬, but Matlab won't recognize the commands `deploytool`, or `mcr`. Therefore now I can't convert it to .exe.

Any idea how can I fix the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trial versions of MATLAB Compiler produce executables that expire at the same time as the trial. To produce a permanent executable you will need to pay for a full license.